# Qt application throws "dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart"

Tags: c++, macos, qt, dylib, dyld

I get well known `dyld` issue on OS X.

Qt.pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.23/include /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/include
LIBS += -L/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.23/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/lib -ljpeg -lpng -ljpeg -lz
```

In runtime my application throws:

> dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart   Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
>   Expected in: /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib  in
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib

I already got this before and I fixed it using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35070568/2656632), but now it occurs again and this advice not works. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 14):

This is only a QtCreator runtime issue. DanyAlejandro's answer (above) is partially correct.

1. Go to Projects -> Run -> "Run Environment" (show Details)
2. I would not recommend **Unset**, rather you should **edit** 
   Both: **DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH** and **DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH**
3. Add */System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Resources:* to the beginning for both paths (colon delimited string)
4. Build project again - this will fix it for good

Comment: Fix my problem, TKS. I think this is system library link path priority issue? Cauz i may installed some other library along with different version of libjpeg by brew : )

Answer (score 7):

In my case, this error would only happen in Qt Creator on OSX ElCapitan (Compiling my OpenCV programs with CLion or XCode in OSX would work without doing anything), so I don't think it's correct to say that a change in the system configuration is mandatory (like your link suggests).

What I did, was to link each library file one by one (linking the dylib files one by one, with their full path). This way, I didn't have to mess with my files or do any extra configuration. For example:

```
LIBS += "/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.dylib"
LIBS += "/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.dylib"
```

Provided such files exist.

**Edit:** Another way to fix this problem (which further proves that this is only Qt Creator related) is to go to *Projects -> Run -> "Run Environment" (show Details)*, select **DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH** and click **Unset**. After this, your project should compile as expected.

Answer (score 3):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509731/dyld-symbol-not-found-cg-jpeg-resync-to-restart) provides a screen shot of finding the setting to change:

I was looking everywhere except the correct spot. I'll walk you through it. You can click the images for bigger versions.

Within Qt Creator, there's a toolbar along the left side of the window. Welcome, Edit, Design, etc. One of the choices is Projects. Select that tab.

[image: The Projects Tab]

From there, there's a new navigation area near the left. Under Build and Run, your Desktop, there's a Run section.

[image: Projects Navigation Section]

That goes to the run settings, and in almost the exact center of that page are the Run settings in a grey box, and one of the items is the checkbox to turn off.

[image: Run Settings]